# Docker Set Up mysql db environment

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, environment

Hello guys im setting up an new wordpress docker machine im on the point to configure my sql db :

```
  db:
    build:
      context: ./Docker/mysql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
        MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    networks:
      - back
```

Dockerfile for sql:

```
FROM mysql:latest
```

this also works fine problem is i don't realy know where i should set the environment props like db name user and so on. any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could set that as environment vars on the server, but if you don't want to do that you could set them for the compose command:

```
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=asdf DB_NAME=mydb DB_USERNAME=user DB_PASSWORD=pw docker compose
```

In the comments you said that you wanted to set the vars in the Dockerfile. Below is an example:

```
FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=asdf
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
ENV MYSQL_USER=user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=pw
```

If you do not want these hardcoded in the Dockerfile, you could combine them with build time arguments.

```
FROM mysql:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$db_root_pw
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=$db_name
ENV MYSQL_USER=$db_username
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=$db_pw
```

Make sure to include the arguments when building the image:

```
docker build --build-arg db_root_pw=rootpw --build-arg db_name=mydb --build-arg db_username=user --build-arg db_pw=pw # [...]
```

Comment: i owuld like to store them in my dockerfile where i do get my sql version "FROM mysql:latest" if possible

Comment: Show your `Dockerfile` in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `environment`, use:

```sh
        env_file:
          - env_file.env
```

and add the env_file.env (or "whateverfilename.env") to your project directory with the following content:

```sh
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpw
MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
MYSQL_USER=myuser
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypw
MYSQL_HOST=myhost
```