# How to secure credentials in a docker-compose file

Tags: linux, docker, security, docker-compose, credentials

in my job I very often setup docker containers that are controlled by a docker-compose file. Often I have to specify credentials in this file, and I don't know how to secure them properly. How to do this?

Here is an example: Consider you want to setup a database with an user jira and a corresponding password, needed for another dockerized application, and you need to specify the password:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=jira'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PasswordInClearTextSoFar'
    networks:
      - my_network
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

That someonse on the host could see the user is bad, but that "PasswordInClearTextSoFar" is visible is something that really annoys me. I don't know how to fix this.

Is it possible to use here system environment variables in the docker-compose file? if yes, how is this correctly done under a linux system?

How would you secure the credentials

Thanks and greetings

Comment: There are lots of options.  Maybe the most basic one is using [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) if you are able to use docker swarm (required).  Then there are some other tools like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).  I wouldn't inject secrets as environment variables, it's typically not considered a secure practice.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61287086/413924) help? Hint: Store just the environment variable **name** in the docker-compose, and the value will come from the host. Combine this with [direnv](https://direnv.net/) and you will not have to worry about secrets again. (and I disagree with the opinion that environment variables are not a good place for secrets.)

Comment: For dotnet we use [app secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=linux).  The problem with env variables are "...If the machine or process is compromised, environment variables can be accessed by untrusted parties"....

Answer (score 2):

For future research on this topic, a possible solution would be to use secrets. As well proposed by other members.

As a reference to the initial need, it would be something like the following:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=/run/secrets/jira-user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/jira-pass
    secrets:
      - jira-user
      - jira-pass
    networks:
      - my_network
secrets:
  jira-user:
    file: ./secrets/jira_usr.txt
  jira-pass:
    file: ./secrets/jira_pwd.txt
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

In the 'secrets' folder, we will have each secret individually with the secret. In the case of the *jira_pwd.txt* file, it will contain:

```
PasswordInClearTextSoFar
```

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯